# alternatives to 3d sensors

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to use a sonar or a sharps Ir sensor in place of a laser scanner or 3d depth sensor like a conenct in the navigation stack? If so please send examples or a very detailed explination.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81601/alternatives-to-3d-sensors/) by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah. I beleive it is possible and you can run navigation stack with Sharp's IR scanner, although the resolution may not be good as the default methods.
See the following links

http://www.showusyoursensors.com/2010/08/ros-and-other-ramblings.html

This is how its done in Pi-Robot

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oDrO5EKU5w

http://www.pirobot.org/blog/0014/

and here is some code

http://code.google.com/p/vanadium-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/arbotix/src/arbotix_sensors/lidar.py?spec=svn19&r=19

---

Originally posted by [achuwilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/1658/achuwilson/) with karma: 128 on 2013-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-09-23**:
Just a note, we pretty much abandoned the PML stuff when the Kinect came out -- it works a lot better with ROS navigation than the slow-updating PML did.

**Comment by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on 2013-09-23**:
do I have to install openni to use the kinect(or other camera depth sensor) with the naviagtion stack?

**Comment by [achuwilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/1658/achuwilson/) on 2013-09-24**:
yes sure, u need openni, Kinect outputs a pointcloud , then using the package pointcloud_to_laserscan (depthimage_to_laserscan in ROS Hydro), you have to fake it as a laserscanner.

**Comment by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on 2013-10-02**:
Parallax sells a 1d laser rangefinder on their website, maybe the PML can be used with that.